# VSCode debugger - 'node' not found error when launching

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to step through my Typescript project with VSCode debugger. However, I encounter this error on launch:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

1. Node is available from the VSCode terminal - `which node` returns `/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/node`
2. The launch conf is as follows:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
}
```

Why does VSCode claim `node` is not available?

Comment: You have installed node?

Comment: Yes, through NVM

Comment: My best guess right now is that VSCode's debugger runs in a shell that does not run the .bashrc script that loads NVM, and that is why it doesn't find node

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I have the same problem.